# Android version 12 - trying to open app but It's crushed by on Runtime Exception

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

**My Mobile version is 12. Work App properly but I upgrade my software version of mobile then crushes.**

[image]

**Show this Error on my log:**

2022-03-01 12:04:55.025 31242-31291/com.Solver.Solver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: WorkManager-WorkManagerTaskExecutor-thread-0
Process: com.Solver.Solver, PID: 31242

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.Solver.Solver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.

Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:147)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:124)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: now with S+ when you are creating `PendingIntent` you have to set one of two mentioned flags... why won't you just do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am solved this error.

I Implements this code.

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing unexpected flags into a `PendingIntent`.

For example:

```
int intentFlags = PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    intentFlags = PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT|PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After several attempt to fix this, i gave up and try to contact Qiscus. And they release new version that handle this Pending Intent behaviour change. So if anyone use Qiscus and got this error, you can use latest tag

https://github.com/qiscus/qiscus-sdk-android/releases/tag/1.3.35

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Intent openIntent = new Intent(context, QiscusPushNotificationClickReceiver.class);
openIntent.putExtra("data", comment);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, QiscusNumberUtil.convertToInt(comment.getRoomId()),
                    openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
} else {
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, QiscusNumberUtil.convertToInt(comment.getRoomId()),
                    openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}




 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Where I use this?

Manifest file or Start Activity?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).